# How to put text in middle of div and position div with margin auto?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move text inside the div in middle of the box and I need to move div box in middle of page.

```css
#move {
  border: 4px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="move">Move Me Center</div>
```

Comment: The answer is in the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. : Add `margin:auto` to make the `div` to the center
2. : Add line-height same as the height of the div that is `line-height:200px;`

```css
#move {
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  margin:auto;
  line-height:200px
}
```

```html
<div id="move">Move Me Center</div>
```

Comment: Red mention that he want this with out using the `margin: auto;`

Comment: @FrayneKonok OP said with `margin:auto` ;)

Answer (score 1):

besides using `line-height` you can create a `span` around text and apply `transform:translateY(50%)` and add `margin:auto` changing `inline-block` to `block` in `#move`

```css
#move {
  border: 4px solid black;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  margin:auto
}
#move span {
  transform: translateY(50%);
  display:block;
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<div id="move">
  <span>Move Me Center</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `line-height` the same as the height of the div: `line-height:200px;`

Answer (score 0):

If your users mostly use modern browsers, you could always use `flexbox` as a solution.

Chris over at CSS-Tricks has a great guide to flexbox, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

## Example

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/ohsnapdevin/pen/mPEvje/)

## HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="move">
  <p>Move me center</p>
</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.flex-container { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row; /* Change to columns for vertical axis */ 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100vw; 
}

.move { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 400px; 
  border: 1px solid red; 
}
```